# Expand last Widget of a ListVew to fill remaining height

Tags: flutter

I've got a `ListView` with two children. The last `Widget` is a `Container` with a blue background color and some content. I want to expand this container to fit the remaining height.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ...,
          coloredForm,
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


Widget coloredForm = Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(15, 20, 70, 1.0),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: const Radius.circular(25.0),
        topRight: const Radius.circular(25.0),
      ),
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ...,
        ...,
        ...,
      ],
    )
);
```

Comment: why `ListView` then .? use - `Column` then wrap second child with `Expanded`.

Comment: but a Column isn't scrollable right? I need it to be flexible and so the scroll is important. Is there no way to fill the remaining height with a listview?

Comment: read the answer below and I'm sure you're good to go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Column` instead of `ListView`.

Then wrap that `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView`

As per your query, your last item should be expanded, but as it's ScrollView, Compiler is confused at `How much to expand?`.

So you have to set some height of last widget.